# How to output dictionary of numpy arrays to file

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

```
from os import listdir
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg19 import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
import numpy as np
import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from pickle import dump
import xlsxwriter
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
import pandas as pd   
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter
import pickle
# load an image from file
path1 = '/home/mclab/Desktop/Test'    #path of folder of images

# extract features from each photo in the directory
def extract_features(directory):
   # load the model
   model = VGG16()
   # re-structure the model
   model.layers.pop()
   model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[-1].output)
   # summarize
   print(model.summary())
   # extract features from each photo
   features = dict()
   for name in listdir(directory):
      # load an image from file
      filename = directory + '/' + name
      image = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
      # convert the image pixels to a numpy array
      image = img_to_array(image)
      # reshape data for the model
      image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
      # prepare the image for the VGG model
      image = preprocess_input(image)
      # get features
      feature = model.predict(image, verbose=0)
      # get image id
      image_id = name.split('.')[0]
      # store feature
      features[image_id] = feature
      print('>%s' % name)
return features
# extract features from all images
directory = path1
features = extract_features(directory)
print('Extracted Features: %d' % len(features))
print (features)
```

I run this code for 4 input images from my data in the given directory. I got my dictionary in this form
features = {'1': array([[0.       , 4.845782 , 0.       , ..., 2.6509986, 0.       ,
        0.       ]], dtype=float32), '3': array([[0.       , 0.5562537, 0.       , ..., 1.1013255, 0.       ,
        0.       ]], dtype=float32), '2': array([[0.11465299, 0.        , 3.7899919 , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]], dtype=float32), '4': array([[0.       , 0.       , 0.       , ..., 0.       , 2.6636925,
        0.       ]], dtype=float32)}

I note that each value in the dictionary is represented by an array of the features of the key image. My question is: how can I save the features array of the input images in an excel file in order to use these features for regression problem.

Comment: @Georgy, I think the structure of the `dict` is actually very different to your dup. OP's dictionary is actually easier to handle since we can aggregate into one `numpy` array, which is, in fact, what you *should* do in this scenario.

Comment: @jpp Apart from more complicated data structure in the linked post, the question is basically the same, so I think it should be marked as a duplicate. But I can be wrong, this is why it says "*Possible* duplicate". :) Nevertheless, your answer fits better this particular case and should definitely stay, this is why I upvoted it.

Comment: @Georgy, not a criticism, I often make the same mistake myself :). I just fear that the user will go to the other post and try to write line-by-line.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to save to CSV using only `numpy` functionality. CSV files can be opened in Excel.

The solution assumes you want to sort by key beforehand. Note that dictionaries are not considered to be ordered. If ordering is important consider using `collections.OrderedDict`.

I have provided a minimal example, which can be applied to arbitrary sized dictionaries.

```
import numpy as np

# example dictionary input
d = {0: np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
     1: np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
     2: np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])}

# build array from dictionary
arr = np.array([v for _, v in sorted(d.items())])

# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
#        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])

# save to array
np.savetxt('out.csv', arr, delimiter=',')
```

If you *really* need to save to `.xlsx` format, you can do so via Pandas:

```
pd.DataFrame(arr).to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks jpp I will try it. Actually each array in my case represent the features vector of an image for example   '1': array([[0., 4.845782, 0., ..., 2.6509986, 0., 0.]], dtype=float32) is the features vector of the image named '1'. So, I need to save the feature vector for each image in an excel file then I can use for regression problem

Comment: @fatma, OK. I've updated with an Excel solution via pandas too.

Comment: For line np.savetxt('out.csv', arr, delimiter=',')
I got  ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead

Comment: @fatma, not sure why. Have you tried the above code as it is? I want to isolate whether this is a problem with your inputs / my logic / different environment.

Comment: this is an example for my input dictionary: {'1': array([[0.       , 4.845782 , 0.       , ..., 2.6509986, 0.       ,
        0.       ]], dtype=float32), '3': array([[0.       , 0.5562537, 0.       , ..., 1.1013255, 0.       ,
        0.       ]], dtype=float32), '2': array([[0.11465299, 0.        , 3.7899919 , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
        0.        ]], dtype=float32), '4': array([[0.       , 0.       , 0.       , ..., 0.       , 2.6636925,
        0.       ]], dtype=float32)}

Comment: @fatma, that doesn't help, e.g. `...` is not valid Python. Please update your post with a *complete* example that other users can replicate.

Comment: I provided the whole function that I have been used. I hope any one can help me.

Comment: @fatma, No, doesn't help. I need a verifiable example of your *data*.

Comment: I updated my post and the output dictionary is obtained after applying this code for four images saved in the given directory. I hope that I explain my question in a good way then I can got some answers as well.